# Imagick installed and enabled and phpinfo does not show

Tags: php, ubuntu

Hi I have tried all that I haven seen in different forums but it has not worked...

I already installed imagick

If I user this command:

```
php -m | grep imagick
```

It returns imagick so it is installed..

[image: imagick]

If I go to phpinfo(); it does not display imagick

You can see that here [phpinfo](http://3.20.205.89/dashboard/phpinfo.php)

If I search it in:

```
nano /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

I can not find it either to check if I can delete the ;

So I wonder what could the problem be?

I am using PHP 7.2, Xampp, Ubuntu with Aws.

Thanks!

Comment: The Apache and CLI modules probably use different `php.ini` files. Add the `extension=imagick.so` line manually to `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`.

Comment: Ok @MatsLindh  I did it, restarted and it does not appear either